# How to find an element using CSS2 Selector in Motoools and hide it?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, mootools

How can i find this span element with class="rocon.rocon-br" in #conttile2 by Mootools' Css Selector? This element is created dynamically by Javascript (rounded corner), so this is what i see in Dragonfly Dom tree for it:

```
html > body > div#wrapper.wrapper > div#penalties.container > h2#conttitle2.rc10.rocon__8.rocon-init > span.rocon.rocon-br
```

There are other elements with this class in tree.

I'm trying to get it and hide like this:

```
$$('h2#conttitle2>span.rocon.rocon-tl').each(function(corners) {corners.setStyle('display','none');});
```

an even

```
$('conttitle2').getElements('span[class=rocon rocon-tl]').each(function(corners) {corners.setStyle('display','none');});
```

But it wont hide at all :(
Can you please advise what would be the correct syntax to achieve this element hidden?

Comment: post the markup / generated html that you are trying to target...

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector:

```
#conttile2 > span[class~="rocon.rocon-br"]
```

The [attribute selector `[attr~=value]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#x16) is for whitespace-separated list like the value of the `class` attribute.

Comment: @moogeek: And your `span` elements are children of the element with the ID *conttile2*?